# Find the value in the minimum number of trials

Tags: php

I have an array of 52 different values that I can pass through a class to get a number in return.

```
$array = array("A","B","C","D"...);
```

Each value passed through the class gives a different number that can be either positive or negative.
The numbers are not equally distributed but are sorted in natural order.

E.g.

```
$myclass->calculate("A"); // 2.3
$myclass->calculate("B"); // 0.25
$myclass->calculate("C"); // -1.3
$myclass->calculate("D"); // -6
```

I want to get the last value that return a number >= 0.20 (in the example would be "B").

This should be done in the minimum number of "class invocation" to avoid time wasting.

I thought something like: divide $array in 2 pieces and calculate the number I get, if it is >= 20, then split the last part of $array in other 2 smaller pieces and so on. But I don't know if this would work.

How would you solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is called a binary search.

Comment: Or Divide and conquer. It would definitely work splitting your array.

Comment: What do you mean for "Divide and conquer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is called a binary search, but it won't really work for this use case, because you aren't searching for a known value.  Rather, you're searching for the value that is the lowest number >= 0.2 in a set where the exact value 0.2 may not exist (if it were guaranteed to exist, then you could do a binary search for 0.2, and then your letter would simply be `n - 1; n != 0`).

If your range is always A-Z, a simple linear search would definitely be the easiest method.  The time savings on a data set of 26 elements for using a more efficient method is negligible (talking milliseconds here), compared to implementation time.

**Edit:**  I see you actually mentioned 52 elements, not 26.  My point is still the same, though.  The number of elements would need to be in the tens of thousands or more for there to be any significant savings, *unless you are performing this operation in a tight loop.*

Comment: I'm not convinced. What do you mean for "linear search"? A sequential search? Because let's consider the value I'm searching is the 20th. I would have to call my class 20 times.
Instead if I divide the array into slices let's say of half array, I would need 52/2 = 26/2 = 13/2 = 7/2 = 3/2 = my value. only 5 calls to the class. Am I wrong, or misunderstood anything?

Comment: Yes, you misunderstand that you are not searching for a known value.  You also misunderstand that I said a linear/sequential search would be *easiest* to implement, not the most efficient, but that on a data set of 52 elements, the efficiency is not a factor unless your letter-to-number function is really expensive (I'm assuming it isn't), or this whole operation is being done in a loop with tons of iterations (also assuming this isn't the case).

Comment: Unfortunately the function is really expensive... it tooks like 1.5 second to get a value in return. So every second earned is gold :D

Comment: 1.5 seconds is quite a long time in terms of processing power... is this function doing a remote network request?

Comment: No, it has to deal with matrices and other Math operations :)